# Why does Output to file not work but print statement does?

Tags: python

I have the following code:

```
for node, value in sorted(d.iteritems()):
    outfile.write([node] + value)
    print(node, value)
```

I read a few different SO posts about this and am still somewhat confused. The print statement works perfectly, printing the key and value correctly in the interpreter. But I couldn't figure out a way to get the outfile.write() statement to work here. Would greatly appreciate any clarification!

Comment: What are the types of `node` and `value`? (It looks like `value` is a list- is that correct? Is it a list of strings?)

Comment: (You could give an example of `d` to indicate this).

Comment: What is going wrong? http://sscce.org/

Comment: @Marcin: This question was already answered and accepted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`print` automatically converts the given variable to a string (using the `__repr__` method). `file.write` does not. You could still write to a file with something like:

```
outfile.write("%s %s\n" % (node, value))
```

(I also added a newline). However, you don't make clear in the question what the types of `node` and `value` are. The expression `[node] + value` implies that `value` is a list. If you want the list to be comma separated (as implied by your question's title) you can combine them and join them with commas like so:

```
outfile.write(",".join(map(str, [node] + value)))
```

Comment: Thanks, David. Node is a string and value is an integer.  Technically though, value no longer needs to be an integer, since it was just a way of incrementing the occurences of "node", and now the result is stored in "d".

Comment: If `value` is an integer, why did you have `[node] + value` in your code above?

Comment: Not a great reason, but I saw this explanation and thought it applied to me as well: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6870103/outputting-a-python-dictionary-with-values-in-an-array-to-a-csv-file

Comment: Also, thanks again for your help. I just tried the outfile.write("%s %s\n" %(node, value) statement and it worked perfectly. Thanks!

Comment: 1) In that case, `value` was a list, not an integer. 2) He was using a csv writer. I've assumed up until now that `outfile` is a file object- is it a `csv.writer`? If so, you should do something different than the above

Comment: No, outfile is a file object here. The answer you gave works perfectly. Thanks David!

Comment: All right, sounds good! (I've removed the `csv` tag from your question lest it be confusing to future readers)